# TFS 2018 Restrict files from being read/opened in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfs-2018

We have an on-premises version of TFS 2018. We have set up a user to have access to the collection under the "Version Control" tab with the following permissions.

[image: TFS Collection Set Up]

I have then drilled down into the projects under the collection and set some of the files (web.config), to be Read = Deny.

[image: TFS Restrictions]

I would have presumed that this setting didn't allow the user to see the contents of the file when opened in Visual Studio. Is this the case or have I misunderstood the setting? If so how can I restrict access to certain files in TFS.

Comment: That setting has nothing to do with Visual Studio. It means they won't be able to download it in the first place. If they already have a copy, they can see it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Just to clarify I have changed the setting after configuring TFS and Visual Studio link, am I right in thinking that for this not to be downloaded in the first place then I would need to remove mapping and remap?